# Swift - Como hago para efectuar una función después de que termine el audio con SKAudioNode y

Tags: swift2

```
backgroundMusic =SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "audio.mp3")
backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = false
addChild(backgroundMusic)    
backgroundMusic.runAction(SKAction.play())
```

Después de que suena todo el audio, necesito ejecutar una función, pero no se como hacerlo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

**OPCIÓN 1**

Tengo un botón que pincho y hace que se achique un `SKSpriteNode` llamado `miaumHelp`, luego si lo presiono de nuevo se agranda, después de agrandarse suena un audio, y se achica, pero se achica antes que termine el audio, no espera el audio, la idea es que termina el audio y después de eso se achique.

Entonces lo que necesito es que después de que suene completo el audio, se achique no antes.

Aquí mi código.

```
if toggleMiaumHelpState {
    toggleMiaumHelpState = false
    miaumHelp.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.2, duration: 0.5), completion: { print("small")})
    backgroundMusic.runAction(SKAction.stop())
} else{
    toggleMiaumHelpState = true
    miaumHelp.runAction(
        SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 0.5), completion: {
            print("big")
            self.backgroundMusic.runAction(
                SKAction.play(),
                completion:{
                    //Se ejecuta de inmediato, no espera que termine el audio.
                    self.miaumHelp.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.3, duration: 0.5), completion: {
                            print("small again 0.3")
                     })
              }  
          )
    })
}
```

**OPCIÓN 2**

Tengo un botón que al hacer pinch hace que disminuya su tamaño un `SKSpriteNode` llamado `miaumHelp`, luego, si lo presiono de nuevo se agranda, después de agrandarse suena un audio, y después se achica, aquí se achica después que termina el audio, pero si presiono el botón de nuevo, no tengo como detener el audio y que no se ejecute la acción `actionSmallAgain`.

Aquí funciona lo del audio, pero no se puede cancelar el sonido ni el efecto que sigue.

```
if toggleMiaumHelpState {
    toggleMiaumHelpState = false
    miaumHelp.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.2, duration: 0.5), completion: {
        print("small")
    })
} else{ 
    toggleMiaumHelpState = true
    miaumHelp.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.5), completion: {
    print("big")    
    self.runAction(
             SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("audio.mp3", waitForCompletion: true)
              ,completion: {
                     self.miaumHelp.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.4, duration: 0.5), withKey: "actionSmallAgain")
                     print("small again")
               }
         )
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser mas específico con lo que estas buscando?  Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar.

Comment: Ahora describí con más detalle mis problema, espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias a mil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo hice con `AVAudioPlayer` la cual tiene una función que se ejecuta cuando termina un audio, llamada:

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
```